# Cannot send RTP by SIPp tool

Tags: sip, sipp

I am trying to replay an captured pcap file with sipp as follows:

In Sending.xml

...

```
<recv response="200" rrs="true">
<action>
<ereg regexp="(.*)" search_in="hdr" header="To:" assign_to="TO_REQUEST"/>
</action>
</recv>

<send >
<![CDATA[
ACK [next_url] SIP/2.0
To: [$TO_REQUEST]
From: [$FROM_REQUEST]
Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port];branch=[branch]
Call-ID: [call_id]
CSeq: [last_cseq_number] ACK
Contact: <sip:[local_ip]:[local_port]> 
[routes]
Max-Forwards: 70
Subject: Performance Test
Content-Length: 0
]]>
</send>

<nop>
<action>
<exec play_pcap_audio="pcap/g711a.pcap"/>
</action>
</nop>
```

...

However, I always get the same error:
extract_rtp_remote_addr: no IP address found in SDP message body.

I tried to test with other *.pcap and *.raw files and edit my script but I still cannot.
When I only send the signal not RTP, the call is successful.

Anyone can help me send RTP by SIPp?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recall I had similar issues with that at some point due to my .pcap not being very 'clean'.

Are you sure the pcap contains just the RTP packets and nothing else?

For a working example of pcap played by sipp, you can check [webrtc-test project](https://github.com/RestComm/webrtc-test) and more specifically: [.pcap](https://github.com/RestComm/webrtc-test/tree/master/resources/pcap) and relevant [sipp xml](https://github.com/RestComm/webrtc-test/blob/master/webrtc-load-tests/webrtc-sipp-client.xml)

Also notice that sipp usually only plays just one direction of the RTP media, so it's best if you have media flowing in both directions to make sure.

Hope this helps.

Best regards,
Antonis Tsakiridis

Comment: I tried with some 'clean' .pcap file and also tried with your .pcap file. However, I still get this error. Can I use any .pcap file or not, or I need to get the .pcap file from the real phone in my lab?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should be able to gather .pcap from any computer on the network where media transfer is being done. Really strange that it still fails with my .pcap, as it is tested. Anyway, maybe it makes sense to directly open an issue at sipp issue tracker: https://github.com/SIPp/sipp/issues

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi atsakiridis, 
currently, after using the older version of SIPp (3.3 instead of 3.4.1 as before)  I can send RTP by SIPp.

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with the SDP in your INVITE. extract_rtp_remote_addr will be looking for an IP address to send the RTP to.

Check your INVITE in the XML has the correct IP address in the c line.